How to connect to a GCP server with service acocunt json key file and run sql queries in C++
I have a .json key file for a service account that I have used to connect to a GCP BigQuery database in a Python script and run SQL queries. All is good in Python and the sql queries work as expected.
I now want to do the same in C++ and have been frustrated to find very little on how to do this, even on the Google Cloud cpp website. Does anyone have example C++ code that shows how to connect to GCP BigQuery with a service account json key file and then run SQL queries on it? I am using MS Visual Studio and manage packages with VCPKG.

Do you use Google Cloud Client libraries for C++?

I have instaleld these 9 google cloud libraries but I haven't found out how to use them to solve my problem:

google-cloud-cpp:x64-windows
google-cloud-cpp[bigquery]:x64-windows
google-cloud-cpp[bigtable]:x64-windows
google-cloud-cpp[grpc-common]:x64-windows
google-cloud-cpp[iam]:x64-windows
google-cloud-cpp[pubsub]:x64-windows
google-cloud-cpp[rest-common]:x64-windows
google-cloud-cpp[spanner]:x64-windows
google-cloud-cpp[storage]:x64-windows
I'd be happy to install any others, but I use VCPKG in MS Visual Studio so they'd have to be available in VCPKG.

